# Check if the current document is saved

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm just wondering if any javascript can check/detect if the current document is already saved or updated.

I've search on the web but I got nothing.

---

**Edit:** If the active document that is open in Illustrator has unsaved changes I want to have an alert that indicates the document has not been saved yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 38 of the [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) titled: [Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 Scripting Reference: JavaScript](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_JavaScript_Scripting_Reference_2017.pdf) it states that the `Document` object has a `saved` property.

It is described as follows:

> ***Property :*** `saved`
>   **Value Type :** `boolean`
>   **Description :** If `true`, the document has not been changed since the last time it was saved.

Therefore you can do the following:

```js
if (!app.activeDocument.saved) {
  alert("The document has changed since the last time it was saved", 'Unsaved Changes', true)
}
```

The example code (above) alerts the user if the `saved` property is `false`.